# Apache Tomcat Maven plugin war not found

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm following the documentation [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/executable-war-jar.html) but I end up with a `jar` that doesn't find the `war` to execute. Here's the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ortizj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\valida
tion-manager\Validation-Manager-Web\target\.extract\webapps\ROOT.war (The system
 cannot find the file specified)
```

For some reason the `war` file is not added to the `jar` so it fails when it's extracting it.

`ROOT.war` exists and is present in the target folder.

Here's the relevant POM contents:

[POM Project](https://github.com/javydreamercsw/validation-manager/blob/0.3.4/pom.xml):

```
 <profile>
        <id>installer</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>tomcat-run</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <warRunDependency>
                                    <dependency>
                                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>Validation-Manager-Web</artifactId>
                                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                                        <type>war</type>
                                    </dependency>
                                    <charset>utf-8</charset>
                                    <httpPort>9078</httpPort>
                                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                                </warRunDependency>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: Just checking: did you construct both poms as in http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/executable-war-jar.html ?  You only show 1 above.

Comment: Updated the question showing both relevant pom files.

Answer (score 3):

How about adding this to your pom.xml file..

```
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                            <warName>your-war-name</warName>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                            <outputDirectory>${deploy-path}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the decency on your war. Therefore it is not included:

```
<warRunDependencies>
  <warRunDependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>a groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>and artifactId</artifactId>
      <version>version</version>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
  </warRunDependency>
</warRunDependencies>
```

Comment: See the updated question with updated POMs as well as link to them. Still I get no war file even after your suggestion.

Comment: You only need to specify the tomcat7-maven-plugin (in the parent pom.xml preferably) and _all_ the configuration has to go there. And I suggest you remove the external context.xml unless you have a very good reason to put it there.

Comment: Did this and still didn't work. I had the context piece since even if I manually placed the war in the .extracted folder and everything seemed to work it failed finding variables defined on the context file.

Comment: If you do need a context.xml you either need to include it into the .war./META-INF or use the tomcatConfigurationFilesDirectory parameter to put it into the Tomcat config directory. Otherwise it will not be avaible in the packaged tomcat executable.

Comment: The context file is already on the war file. Can't understand why it wouldn't find it. The war file deploys fine to Tomcat but for some reason fails in the embedded one.

Comment: Because the embedded one does not have the context.xml in the proper location. It either has to stored as META-INF/context.xml which it is not. Or it has to be stored in the config directory of tomcat as <engine>/<your_context>.xml which requires you to use the tomcatConfigurationFilesDirectory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148451/discussion-between-javydreamercsw-and-fhossfel).

Comment: Is this now fixed?

Comment: No, could not build it because there is a compilation error in your code [ERROR] symbol:   method setDisplayedMaxTitles(int)
[ERROR] location: variable w of type org.vaadin.teemu.wizards.Wizard
[ERROR] /Users/felix/src/validation-manager/Validation-Manager-Web/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/javydreamercsw/validation/manager/web/execution/ExecutionWindow.java:[98,18] cannot find symbol

Comment: I will try with another war.

Comment: You probably missed compiling all projects dependencies. The project you mention is there as a sub module. git submodule update --init --recursive then mvn -DskipTests=true install --also-make-dependents

Comment: I think XML files do not depend on the decency of their arrangement

Comment: Sorry, I have not yet had time to look into this. I am from Hamburg and we had a bit of civil war over the last couple of days.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Hope everything is fine.

Answer (score -1):

As a alternative for tomcat, You can use jetty as server.
Therefore POM should be added flowing plugins.

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <warName>myapp</warName>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.5.v20170502</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/myapp</contextPath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

You can run it as following.

```
mvn clean install
mvn jetty:run
```

You app will be start on default port 8080 under given context (In this "myapp").

Comment: This doesn't address the question. This requires sources, etc to run the server. I want a stand alone option to distribute as the Tomcat plugin is supposed to do.